# Finding continuous elements in a collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections

If I have
 an array like this:

```
int[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,1,5,5,51,5,5,12,5,5,5};
```

I would like to use Linq to return an array defining each starting index where 2 or more entries are the same as the previous index. So using the above array I would like the return array to be.

4,9,12,15
where the array elements happen to be 5 but the value is not important.

is this possible or should I use a foreach loop to make things easier to read?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please rephrase

Comment: Yeah, what is continuous? `1,2,3,4,5` or `5,5,5,5,5`?

Comment: So do you want to simply return `5,5,5,5` or the index where the sequence is found?

Comment: Please provide an indication of the *output* you are looking for for that input

Comment: Sorry I mean the elements == 5.There are  continous set of elements == 5 starting at index 4 index 9 and 12 etc

Comment: I don't know what to try that is why I am asking. I want n number of sets of value 5.

Comment: Is this `var fives = nums.Where(x => x == 5).ToList();` you are looking for or I totally don't understand a question? If you want the number of '5' that are in this array then change `ToList()` to `Count()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
From index 4, value 5 repeated 4 time(s)
From index 9, value 5 repeated 2 time(s)
From index 12, value 5 repeated 2 time(s)
From index 15, value 5 repeated 3 time(s)
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1,
                     5, 5, 51, 5, 5, 12, 5, 5, 5 };
        foreach(var block in nums.FindBlocks())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "From index {0}, value {1} repeated {2} time(s)",
                block.Item1, block.Item2, block.Item3);
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, T,int>> FindBlocks<T>(
              this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var eq = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        using(var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if(iter.MoveNext())
            {
                T last = iter.Current;
                int startIndex = 0, count = 1, index = 1;
                while(iter.MoveNext())
                {
                    var cur = iter.Current;
                    if(eq.Equals(last,cur))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(count >= 2)
                        {
                            yield return Tuple.Create(startIndex, last, count);
                        }
                        count = 1;
                        last = cur;
                        startIndex = index;
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                if (count >= 2)
                {
                    yield return Tuple.Create(startIndex, last, count);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good solution but I don't think that OP will understand any of it...:)

Comment: Is this *honestly* how you would solve this problem? :) If so, what does this approach offer over a simple `foreach` over an `int[]`?

Comment: @rosko "loop over the data; check whether the current item is the same as the previous item; if so increment a counter, otherwise check if the last block was 2 or more (and report if so), and reset the block; when done, check whether the last block was 2 or more, as we won't have reported it yet" - better?

Comment: @RGraham it *is* a simple `foreach`, over an arbitrary source; the main reason I've used the iterator API directly (which only adds the visible `.MoveNext()`/`.Current`) is because it makes it very easy to initialize and special-case the first item

Comment: Yes a little but its too hardcore code for a beginner to understand but thats just my opinion. @RGraham may be right, maybe some simple `foreach` would be better.

Comment: @MarcGravell You know what I mean. Get down from there! I'm not upvoting this answer because it's genuinely *not helpful*. It's clever, but it's not helpful. Understanding this answer requires understanding of EqualityComparer, Enumerators, extension methods, the `yield` operator, the `Tuple` class and finally generics.

Comment: I didn't phrase the question very well - but I see what you guys are saying - thanks.

Comment: @TheJack do you understand the code in this answer?

Comment: Not really a little too in depth for my understanding but I see how to do it from the comments. It is a hardcore answer  but that's cool.Lol.

Comment: @RGraham you are entitled to your view; however, please also feel free to offer your own easier to understand alternative answer. Because I'm pretty sure that this answer is a **lot** more useful than a non-existent one. And no, it doesn't demand understanding of any of those things: the code works fine without that. However, it perhaps *increases* understanding of those things. The only way to learn how tuples (for example) work is *to see them being used*. Ditto generics, iterator blocks, extension methods, equality-comparer, etc. The OP is free to ask questions on any aspect of this answer.

Comment: @MarcGravell then your answers are really poor in quality if you think that plain code without explaining anything do the trick.

Comment: @MarcGravell I didn't offer an answer as I didn't understand the question. I'm not arguing that the code doesn't *work*, I'm simply stating that it wasn't going to *help* the OP. IMO, posting understandable code is more helpful than posting code the OP is just going to copy/paste. Not to take anything away from your answer! It's nice code, I appreciate the explanation and I certainly wouldn't downvote it. I just thought I would offer an explanation as to why I couldn't upvote it.

Comment: @rosko should I add "increment the variable count by one" next to `count++;`? IMO the code says exactly what it does already; if there are specific questions on any part of it, I will be more than happy to go into ridiculous levels of detail, but I'm not going to do that unless there is an actual "can you tell me what {this bit} means?"

Comment: @MarcGravell you are rather funny guy and don't understand what I and RGraham said... but ok you are an expert here.

Comment: @rosko I understand; I just don't agree. It isn't a pi**ing contest, and I'm not trying to be dismissive. I just think you've perhaps both been a little overly negative without actually being constructive anywhere.